# Inverting $B + TCT'$ if $T$ is of full rank

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In Leeuw & Meijer (2008) 'Handbook of multilevel analysis', I found the following theorem (p. 72):

If $A = B + TCT'$ with A and B positive definite, then

$A^{-1} = B^{-1} - B^{-1}T(C^{-1}+T'B^{-1}T)^{-1}T'B^{-1}$

(*note*: In the handbook, the bracket term is written as $(C^{-1}+T'C^{-1}T)^{-1}$ but think this is a typo. See: Henderson et al. 1980: On Deriving The Inverse Of a Sum of Matrices, equation 17).

Anyway, the theorem 1.2 is clear. But the authors proceed and state that if, in addition, $T$ is of full rank, then:

$A^{-1} = T(T'T)^{-1}(C+(T'B^{-1}T)^{-1})^{-1}(T'T)^{-1}T'+[B^{-1}-B^{-1}T(T'B^{-1}T)^{-1}T'B^{-1}]$

How to derive this identity?

Comment: I fixed your first statement, since it differed from Theorem 1.2 of your quoted source

Comment: My version of Leeuw & Meijer has a reference with a proof for this statement btw.

Comment: It is known as the Woodbury Matrix Identity https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity

Comment: @LinAlg, it does mention a reference. A report from 1993 that has not been published in any journal. Despite some internet research I was not able to find this reference. Have you?

Comment: @LinAlg, the way theorem 1.2 is presented in the handbook is wrong. I am sure it is a typo.See  en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity. This is why I presented it the way I did.

Comment: @JeanMarie, I know of this identity and this is why the first line of the theorem presented is clear. However, the extension is the problem and is also not covered by the wikipedia link presented. Any ideas on my question?

Comment: I just mentionned the name for the sake of completeness, for readers that would like to dig into the subject. About the extension, sorry, I have no idea ; usually, block matrix calculations are the best way of attack for this kind of issues.

Comment: @DomB see [Majorization Algorithms for Mixed Model Analysis](http://gifi.stat.ucla.edu/janspubs/1993/reports/deleeuw_liu_R_93.pdf).

Comment: @LinAlg, thanks a lot for sharing! I think this is what I have been looking for. Much appreciated